# Get co-ordinates equivalent to photoshop co-ordinates

Tags: android, android-canvas

[I want similar effect in android with same co-ordinates given in photooshop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMhNI.png) I have co-ordinates from photoshop  as following

```
   double radius = 317.5;

  // Top-left corner
    double centerX = 741.50 ;
    double centerY = 1175.50;
```

I want android device equivalent co-ordinates for the above co-ordinates .
What im trying now is 
scalingFactor  = get_width_of_device/get_width_of_photoshopcanvas

then `radius = radius* scalingFactor`

but i am not getting correct co-ordinates in my phone which has density as 2.0

Kindly help me whats doing wrong.

Comment: what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want the equivalent co-ordinates of photoshop in my app so that it will work with all the android phones..

Comment: what Photoshop has got to do with that? you mean physical pixel coords?  tried drawable-nodpi folder?

Comment: canvas.drawCircle((float)centerX, (float)centerY,(float) radius, mPaint);I want to draw a circle of same dimesions as photoshop but device specific.

Comment: so place your jpg / png in res/drawable-nodpi and draw it with `drawBitmap`

Comment: Actually there are two circles which are intersecting and i have to draw the path of intersection.So i dont think i can highlight the path of intersection when i draw 2 bitmaps.Hence im trying this way

Comment: sorry i have no idea what you are talking about

Comment: I added an image link.I want to achive this kind of circles in custom view and i have to draw the intersection path with different color

Comment: so whats the problem? call `Canvas#drawBitmap` and `Canvas#drawCircle` twice

Comment: I am talking about the co-ordinates .I need 2 circles which are intersecting and i know the points from psd. I want to replica same points in my screen but it is not at same position due to different width and height

Comment: if you know the centers of the circles and their radii, so whats the problem really? you have everything you need to call `Canvas#drawCircle`... (public void drawCircle(float cx, float cy, float radius, Paint paint))

Comment: I know the centre ,radii but when i draw with those values the circle position is at bottom of the screen and the UI at the bottom gets overlapped with this view.because the devices are of different screen sizes,it draws at wrong position as other UI gets effected

Comment: so your image is bigger that your screen? is it what you mean?

Comment: Yes..I have this issue

Comment: so scale your canvas to fit your image, do not scale your radius